# Archimate - tag elements

Tags: archimate

I am trying to implement a view in the Archimate but I want to be able to filter elements based on the tag in this view.

For example:

```
Feature_A - have two kind of tags ->  tag_A and tag_B
```

Is there a way to specify the tags, so in view I would be able to filter elements by them?

Thank you